# MySQL- what does the WHERE clause do in the correlated subquery here

Tags: mysql, where-clause, correlated-subquery

Quoting from [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-subquery/) :

"In the following query, we select products whose buy prices are greater than the average buy price of all products in each product line.

```
SELECT 
    productname, 
    buyprice
FROM
    products p1
WHERE
    buyprice > (SELECT 
            AVG(buyprice)
        FROM
            products
        WHERE
            productline = p1.productline)
```

"

You can find the executable code in an editor [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/tryit/query/mysql-subquery/#7) . If I just omit the `WHERE` clause, the result seems to be same except the last 2 rows do not appear in the output result.

What do the left and right sides of the `WHERE` clause exactly do here i.e. what values they get each time, how the comparison takes place etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query return productnames which have a buyprice greater than the average of buyprice of all products on the same productline.

```
SELECT 
    productname, 
    buyprice
FROM
    products p1
WHERE
    buyprice > (
        SELECT AVG(buyprice) --return the average buyprice of all products
        FROM products
        WHERE productline = p1.productline  -- same productline
    )
```

Comment: what values do the left and right sides of the `WHERE` clause get each time ? How does the comparison take place ?

Comment: Do you mean the left of the ">" sign, if yes, it compares all the buyprice in your products table to the average of the buyprices of all products

Example: 

ProductName: A, buyprice: 1 and 
ProductName: B, buyprice: 2
 
The Average is 1.5 and your query will return B because 2 is greater than 1.5

Comment: I meant the left and right sides of the equality operator of the `WHERE` clause .

Comment: Ok, so you need to imagine this is a join statement. It will return the product greater than the average of buyprice of each productline. If you have 3 productlines, the subquery will return 3 averages, one for each productline.

Am I clear enough :)?

Answer (score 0):

AVG() calculates the average price. The where compares your items buyprice against the average and only list those that are mnore expensiv,

Comment: Read the last line of the OP .